# Sonar and Jacoco : How to ? (Compatibility with Cobertura)

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

I know there are lot of questions about Sonar and Jacoco not generating the report correctly on SO but none of them helped me solve my problem:

**Here is the deal :**

I have a project using Cobertura to calculate code coverage and I can't change that. Sonar must use Cobertura for the server-side. But on the other hand I have this client (we're talking about a webapplication using smartGWT in java) which is tested with Selenium RC (because that's the only way to test smartGWT).

Cobertura can't calculate Selenium tests' coverage because those tests are done on the deployed application. Jacoco can calculate that because it is launched as a java agent. So everything is working fine on my computer. The jacoco.exec is generated successfully. But it seems that Sonar can't find how to read that file or maybe it's just cobertura and jacoco that are conflicted...

Here is the error that Jenkins generate :

```
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\JENKINS-SONAR\jobs\agepro PROTO\workspace\target\surefire-reports
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:323)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:338)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\JENKINS-SONAR\jobs\agepro (Accès refusé)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:177)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt_9w37ty.controller.LocalController.startup(LocalController.java:46)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt_9w37ty.JacocoAgent.init(JacocoAgent.java:83)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt_9w37ty.JacocoAgent.premain(JacocoAgent.java:165)
    ... 6 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Exception in thread "main"
```

And here is my configuration of the surefire plugin :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-javaagent:${sonar.jacoco.jar}=destfile=${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</argLine>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/Selenium*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>surefire-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- <argLine>-javaagent:${sonar.jacoco.jar}=destfile=${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</argLine> -->
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>none</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/Selenium*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <goal>selenium-test</goal>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Do you see any mistake I could have made ? Or maybe I have to set another path for the jacoco jar or something else ? Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: and one a side note, I think it is not possible to mix cobertura and jacoco for one project. You need to have (not sure if) 2 projects.

Comment: @oers I guess I'll have to create 2 projects or test everything with jacoco...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `reportPath` is a bit misleading.

The setting `sonar.jacoco.reportPath` needs to point to a file and not to a directory.

You seem to have set it to: `D:\JENKINS-SONAR\jobs\agepro`: But I think you mean `D:\JENKINS-SONAR\jobs\agepro\jacoco.exec`

On further inspection I noticed that the problem might be that you working directory "agepro PROTO" has a space in it.

This breaks the syntax for the java agent configuration. Can you get rid of the space(I don't know if `destfile='${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}'` would work)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2823217 This is how I set my variables. Is it wrong ? I'm currently pointing at ${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec.

Comment: Oh the problem might be that you working directory "agepro PROTO" has a space in it. This breaks the syntax for the java agent execution. Can you get rid of the space. I dont know if destfile='${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}' would work.

Comment: I will give it a try. So you think that's the javaagent that could not be launched ? Isn't it that Sonar can't find the jar ? Does ${settings.localRepository} works on a Jenkins ?

Comment: if you look at the stacktrace, you see that it originates from the java agent:  at org.jacoco.agent.rt_9w37ty.JacocoAgent.init(JacocoAgent.java:83). So the jar was found but I think the file could not be created. I don't know whats In ${settings.localRepository}  so I can't answer that :)

Comment: Right, thanks I'll give it a try and mark your answer as accepted if it work and then complete my blog for unit testing smartGWT (if you want to have a look : http://noobdevelopper.tumblr.com/)

Comment: Now it builds. Though I still don't get code coverage and I don't know why... Cobertura seems to be launched before Jacoco is. That's weird. Any idea ?

Comment: which coverage is 0% jacoco or cobertura? are the files empty too? I assuma that cobertura und jacoco are not running in the same jvm?

Comment: Sonar code coverage is at 0%. My jacoco.exec isn't empty. I think they are running in the same JVM. Though it's hard to tell since I don't know how Sonar works. https://gist.github.com/2823912 This is what Jenkins write me. Everything seems to work fine and on the jenkins the jacoco.exec isn't empty :/

Comment: Sonar executed the cobertura sensor: Sensor CoberturaSensor done: 62 ms, this tells you that it used cobertura as a coverage metric. YOu can't mix cobertura and jacoco I'm afraid. I see in your linked first example that you defined jacoco, did you redefine sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin to cobertura somewhere else?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11868/discussion-between-oers-and-depado)

Comment: I can't go in chat because I'm at work. My proxy blocks that stackoverflow chat. And no I didn't redifined it elsewhere... Maybe in the Sonar configuration but I think I can do everything in the pom. That's weird, that's the only problem remaining now ><

Comment: configuration in pom.xml should come before configuration in the sonar server, but I am not sure. are all .java files for the classes that should be covered in src/main/java?

Comment: No it's for unit testing purpose, so they are all in the src/test and have a common pattern to split the unit tests from the others. But it has all been done in the pom.xml (with surefire plugin)

Comment: I believe that sonar only measures and shows the coverage of files that are under src/main/java. Code coverage is not evaluated for the test files. But I'm not 100% sure about this. I use ant and not maven :)

Comment: http://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/MIFOS/How+to+get+setup+sonar+coverage+report+for+integration+tests ?

Comment: Oh hem... My tests are in /src/test but my code that I test is in /src/main. I misunderstood what you asked ^^' By the way that's what I did : <argLine>-javaagent:${sonar.jacoco.jar}=destfile=${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</argLine>

Comment: sry I think I can't help further. I would try to take the jacoco file and produce a report by hand to find out if sonar is messing things up. [But this only seems to be available for ant.](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html). Or you could try the [jacoco maven plugin](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/index.html).

Comment: No problem thanks for helping me with the javaagent that was not working. (as you solved my error)